# How to assign a key on my keyboard to my Mouse?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

Ok, so this is a weird question as it makes my mouse next to useless while this is active.

I want to be able to click my mouse and it in turn think will I'm pressing a key on my keyboard instead of clicking the mouse. Is this even possible?

I want to use it so I can play a game called Rogue Legacy (a platformer). Because currently there is no way to bind your mouse to attack, which is really annoying to me.

This is not a duplicate, this is why: I'm trying to bind my left click on my mouse to press the F key on my keyboard instead of registering it as a left click from the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible with a standard mouse. However. [Logitech](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/gaming-mice) and [Razer](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-mice) sell gaming mouses that have 5, 7, and even more buttons on them that each can be assigned or mapped to a function on the keyboard.

This would be your best bet as it doesn't render your mouse clicks useless and you still get to click a button on the mouse to activate a key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a program like [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) to remap an action to one that can be mapped?  It's generally designed to help programs support more advanced pointing devices, like multi-button mice or trackballs.

I use it to manage my trackball under Windows 8.x (because the OEM software is terrible), but it might work for your scenario.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Yea, I looked at it, but it only lets me use alt ctrl shift and things like that, none of which can be bound as a key in the game :(